# What is the difference between "data" and "information"?

Tags: meaning

So I've always assumed that data and information are the same thing, however, someone I know told me that there is a difference between them, but neglected to tell me said difference.

Could someone please tell me the difference

Thanks.

(PS. Sorry for asking a stupid question)

Comment: Information is data that has been analysed and interpreted.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica - I would say that data can ***contain*** information. Information may be ***extracted from*** data through analysis and interpretation.

Comment: @Jim - It's an interesting point but data is nothing without interpretation.  For example, if I send you a message containing the number 9, it means nothing to you (or to anyone else) until we have agreed what it means. It could be the age of my child or the number of the bus you should take to visit me.